# Unison: skip any delete of files or folders

Tags: synchronization, unison

While synchronising directories using Unison I want to skip any delete of files or folders (both ways).
I wonder how I can do it?

Comment: I'm curious: why would you want to do this? It seems to defeat some of the purpose of keeping thing synchronized with Unison.

Comment: I want to know an answer to this question, especially about folders (directories). Such a method will be useful when the two replicas are stored on storages of limited sizes, for example. Let A be the genuine replica of large size, and let B and C be subtrees of A. I can re-construct A by merging B and C without manual resolution of conflict as long as B and C are identical for their common parts. This way I can hold a large virtual tree over small distributed storages. (I need a way to distinguish deletion to save local space from deletion from the virtual tree.)